# How can I populate javascript array using XSLT (Reading values from XML)

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I have the following requirement.
I need to populate a javascript array with values reading from an input XML file using XSLT.
I just need to read XML using XSLT and populate an array in javascript.

Can anybody has any idea regarding this, it would of great help to me. I am struck at this point. i can't proceed any further without getting this done.

Thanks,
Deepty.K

Comment: Sounds like you need to learn XSLT. O’Reilly does a decent book on the subject, called “Learning XSLT” (http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596003272). There’s also a w3schools tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/

Answer (score 1):

Why would you like to use a formatting language (XSLT) applied to a data format (XML) to get a data format (Javascript array)? The usual way would be to open the XML directly in Javascript using the `XmlHttpRequest` object and the `returnXML` method after successful loading.